# Populating elastic server using logtash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am using elastic search 2.0 , i am using logtash to put the data into es cluster .The data size is 98gb and it takes almost a day using this configuration script

```
# logstash -f logstash-all.conf file: simple-out.conf
input {
    jdbc {
        # sqlserver jdbc connection string to our database, DB
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://dbaddress:1433;databaseName=DB"
        # The user we wish to execute our statement as
        jdbc_user => "abc"
        jdbc_password => "a@"
        # The path to our downloaded jdbc driver
        jdbc_driver_library => "C:/es/elasticsearch-2.2.0/elasticsearch-2.2.0/plugins/jdbc/sqljdbc4-4.0.jar"
        # The name of the driver class for sql server
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        # our query
        statement => "SELECT * from abc"
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        index => "reporting"
        document_type => "perm"
        document_id => "%{elasticid}"
        hosts => "localhost"
    }
}
```

Is there a faster way to dump the data in elastic server from sql server ?
What is importance of data folder in Elastic search bin directory?It seems to get populated when the above script runs

Thanks

Comment: Do you have to download all the data from the database, or is there a timestamp field where you can just grab the new stuff?

Comment: i have to download the whole data

Answer (score 0):

You can put your data into ES using simple bash, like this:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/megacorp/employee/3 -d '{
    "first_name" : "Douglas",
    "last_name" : "Fir",
    "age" : 35
}'
```

but here you need export your record from db into JSON.

Also you can use bulk insert, like this:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/megacorp/employee/_bulk?pretty' \
--data-binary "@/tmp/data.json"
```

and your `@/tmp/data.json` should looks like:

```
{"index":{"_id":"11"}}
{"name":"Amber","age":32}
{"index":{"_id":"12"}}
{"name":"Hattie","age":36}
```

Here you just need dump your data from sql server into such JSON file.

Comment: this is using the curl way ,isnt logtash providing something out of the box to dump the large data into ES

Comment: @srisf I guess logstash under the hood use  curl too... not sure, but i think so...

Comment: so if i have a table to dump of size 100 gb ,i should create 1 json file containing all the records and then using _bulk command

Comment: @srisf No, you have to create 20 or more separated files and import them in parallel...